# Getting this error: mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF> while Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While running a Spark SQL, I am getting `mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>` error.

I checked the common syntax errors which can occur but didn't find any.

```sql
val prevPartitionDate = spark.sql(
"select to_date(concat(year_p,'-',month_p,'-',day_p)) 
from ips.command_room_table 
where 
to_date(concat(year_p,'-',month_p,'-',day_p)) < to_date(concat($yearAsInt,'-',$monthAsInt,'-',$dayAsInt)) 
group by year_p, month_p, day_p 
order by to_date(concat(year_p,'-',month_p,'-',day_p)) desc limit 1"
).first.getDate(0)
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: did u check "$" sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries, able to figure out the issue. As I was using the variables in the query, I just have to add 's' at the beginning of the query like this:

```
val prevPartitionDate = spark.sql(s
"select to_date(concat(year_p,'-',month_p,'-',day_p)) 
from ips.command_room_table 
where 
to_date(concat(year_p,'-',month_p,'-',day_p)) < to_date(concat($yearAsInt,'-',$monthAsInt,'-',$dayAsInt)) 
group by year_p, month_p, day_p 
order by to_date(concat(year_p,'-',month_p,'-',day_p)) desc limit 1"
).first.getDate(0)
```